# Is there a way to enforce that nodes in a JTree must be unique, preferably without writing an implementation of TreeModel?

Tags: java, swing, jtree

I'm currently trying

```
DefaultMutableTreeNode root = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) model.getRoot();

DefaultMutableTreeNode child = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("String");

if (model.getIndexOfChild(root, child) == -1) {
    model.insertNodeInto(child, root, root.getChildCount());
}

model.reload(root);
```

I've also tried using the ['isNodeChild()' method in `MutableTreeNode`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/tree/DefaultMutableTreeNode.html#isNodeChild%28javax.swing.tree.TreeNode%29) instead of the `getIndexOfChild()` method on the TreeModel.

This seems like it should be a pretty trivial thing to do: Take a given node in the tree and see if there is a child node with the specified value (in this case, a `String`) that already exists. If there is, do not add a new child node. Otherwise, add the node as a child.

Suggestions?

Comment: really not because any value in JTrees view can by modified in TreeCellRenderer, RowFilter has access to model only

Comment: what's the problem? BTW: don't call reload - inserting with model api takes care of proper notification

Comment: @kleopatra check my answer below. model.getIndexOfChild() is not doing what he thinks it should. When he searches to see if the index exists, its not searching for the string, it's searching for the DefaultMutableTreeNode.

Comment: @JosephBueno Yeah. I think the way two nodes are compared is not what I expected. I expected them to be compared based on contents, but they don't appear to be.

Comment: @JosephBueno good catch - would have lost my money in betting that DMTN had its equals overridden ;-) Which would be an alternative.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the code is pretty easy to read. Just loop through each and track if it is unique. If you care to track it, it returns true/false if it was added

Test of the method

```
DefaultMutableTreeNode child = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("String");
DefaultMutableTreeNode child1 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("String");
DefaultMutableTreeNode child2 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("String1");

addUniqueNode(child, model);  // Will get added
addUniqueNode(child1, model); // Will not get added
addUniqueNode(child2, model); // Will get added
```

Method:

```
public boolean addUniqueNode(DefaultMutableTreeNode childNode, DefaultTreeModel model)
{
    DefaultMutableTreeNode root = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) model.getRoot();

    // Check each node
    boolean isUnique = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < model.getChildCount(root); i++)
    {
        Object compUserObj = ((DefaultMutableTreeNode) model.getChild(root, i)).getUserObject();
        if (compUserObj.equals(childNode.getUserObject()))
        {
            isUnique = false;
            break;
        }
    }

    // If Unique, insert
    if(isUnique)
        model.insertNodeInto(childNode, root, root.getChildCount());

    return isUnique;
}
```

Comment: Makes sense. I was kind of hoping that this functionality would be built-in somehow, since it seems like it would be very common.

Comment: repeating: don't call model reload .. the insertNodeInto already takes care of the notification. Plus better not compare the objects by toString if we know all nodes are of type DMTN, compare their userObjects

Comment: @kleopatra, I updated with your suggestion of not calling reload. In the question, he stated that he wanted the string values to be unique. Can you elaborate on your removal of not using toString()?

Comment: it's both unsafe and incomplete. Unsafe because your method should handle all types of DMTN and subclasses might have their toString overridden. Incomplete in the general case (as you correctly stated the use-case at hand explicitly asks for using Strings as userObject :-) because userObjects can be of any type

Comment: @kleopatra - ah, I see. You should add another answer to this question. I'm sure others who come across this question would appreciate it. As would I :-)

Comment: one last caveat: user objects might be null :-) Anyway, +1 for solving the problem and steadily improving your answer!